# How to solve python bug without root permission

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, python

Python has a bug that can be fixed by modifying a file in `/usr/lib/`. But I don't have permission to edit that file, is there any way to solve this problem? Is it possible to overwrite that solution in the code's folder?

The following python code uses `pxssh` package to connect to a computer using `ssh` and runs a command on that machine.

```
import pxssh
import getpass
try:                                                            
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
    username = raw_input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login (hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline ('uptime')   # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print s.before          # print everything before the prompt.
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed on login."
    print str(e)
```

But when I run this program, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    s.login (hostname, username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.py", line 243, in login
    if not self.synch_original_prompt():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.py", line 134, in synch_original_prompt
    self.read_nonblocking(size=10000,timeout=1) # GAS: Clear out the cache before getting the prompt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 824, in read_nonblocking
    raise TIMEOUT ('Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().')
pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
```

I am sure that my host credentials are correct (I can directly connect to them using `ssh`). I searched about the problem and it seems that this is a [bug in python](https://bitbucket.org/shipcod3/commandsshbotnet/src) and can be resolved by editing the file `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.py` which I don't have permission to edit. What is the best way to work this out without modifying that file and gaining root access on this machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved by just copying the package `pxssh.py` into my source directory and modifying that file according to the bug report statements.

Generally in python, one can copy the packages in an optional folder and add the address of those folders to the python environment variables; Then they will override the others.